# Local convergence to a fixed point

Tags: numerical-methods

Was wondering if someone could maybe help point me in the right direction with this question? Not really sure how to approach it. (But before you state the theorem about divergence cause derivative is not bounded by 1, take note that I'm already aware of this theorem.)

"Let $x = F(x)$ be a fixed point form for which the sequence $x_k$ diverges because $|F'(s)| > 1$. Prove that the fixed point form $x = F^{-1}(x)$ (where $F^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse of $F$) generates a locally convergent sequence to a fixed point of $F$."

Comment: Hint : if $|F'(s)|>1$ then what can you say about $F'^{-1}(s) = \large\frac{1}{|F'(s)|}$?

Comment: It would be bounded below by 1 - Is that a rule? I've never heard that $F'^{-1}(s) = 1/|F'(s)|$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem, scroll down to 'Statement of the theorem' , it can be applied here because the point $(s,s) \in F$ as $x=s$ is a fixed point of $F$